# Looking for video software for analysing videos

Tags: video, video-editor

I have a security camera on my car which is triggered by motion detection.
Each time it happens it records about 10 seconds in dual cameras which end up with two files `A_[timestamp]`for front, `B_[timestamp]` for rear view.

I want a suggestions for free/paid software which can do the following:

1. Open all videos of type `A` or `B` at once and linking them to one  timeline viewable video- please note I prefer not to create a new long video out of all, just to view them sequential with being able to adjust time more fast/slow in the timeline.
2. Being able to analyze video and tagging the sections which persons are recognized.

Comment: What do you mean by analyze? "Computer, zoom in and enhance" is a bit of TV/film artistic license still.

Comment: If what you're asking is how to edit multicam sequences, Adobe Premiere can do this very easily.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that this question is a duplicate of one of the questions below:

[What Beginner Video Editing Software Should I Use?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/3018/what-beginner-video-editing-software-should-i-use)

[Free video editing software](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/14820/free-video-editing-software)

Answer (score 0):

I use an editing software called Sony Vegas pro 13. It can handle as many video clips as I want. And it will give you the advantage of stitching the footage together, zooming in and also taking images from the footage.